# JSON.parse() from localStorage issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html, local-storage

I am currently working on a little browser game and I am using the HTML localStorage to save some data.

The problem:
I have an empty array that i will later `.push()` some data into. I am storing this array in the localStorage but when i try to read from the local storage it doesn't work.

The Chrome Developer Tools console is giving me this error:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u" when trying to parse the data from localStorage.

Here's the code i am using:

```
var allContracts = [];
localStorage["allContracts"] = JSON.stringify(allContracts);

allContracts = JSON.parse(localStorage["allContracts"]);
```

There is more code than this but none of it is interacting with these in any way.

Is there a quirk with localStorage or JSON that i am not aware of and is causing this? (i am not very familiar with JSON or localStorage)
Should i be doing this a different way?
Or am i just missing an obvious mistake?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Works just fine for me ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on latest chrome, even after adding a `push` after your parse and writing again.

Comment: Couldn't replicate either, you need to provide more details.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: @Vlad2000Andrei maybe it's better if you accept my answer instead of the answer without explanation...

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude oops, tried accepting multiple answers...
yeah... you can tell i am new around here :P

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude are you kidding? The MDN documentation is perfectly clear. You can use localStorage as an object and the data will be stored permanently. Try it if you don't believe me...

Comment: The data must be only strings, otherwise it crashes. If you don't use `getItem()` and `setItem()` methods, you can store incorrect vaues that produces that error (in this case the error is the `undefined` value). I explain it in the comment of my answer.

Comment: I'm not suggesting not to use `getItem()` and `setItem()`. I'm saying that what you said (`With your piece of code, you are overriding the localStorage global object with your own values, so you lost the functionality.`) is not correct. You can use localStorage as an object and the data you set will be stored permanently. This is why no one is able to reproduce @Vlad2000Andrei's error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use the methods that the interface of `localStorage` serves to you. It have `setItem()` and `getItem()` methods, so why not use to safe yourself?

```
var allContracts = [];
// setter
localStorage.setItem("allContracts",  JSON.stringify(allContracts));
//getter
var allContracts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allContracts"));
```

With your piece of code, you are overriding the `localStorage` global object with your own values, so you lost the functionality.

You make this:

```
localStorage = [] // transform the default localstorage into an array
```

And you need this:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value)
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Did you reproduce the issue?

Comment: That's a correct answer. Did you read carefully all my post? Can you tell us what's your problem?

Comment: You didn't explain why he was getting the error. I tried to reproduce the issue but couldn't.

Comment: You'll notice that others tried to reproduce it as well.

Comment: I explain it, but you don't understand it. I said: `With your piece of code, you are overriding the localStorage global object with your own values, so you lost the functionality.`

Comment: You think that the oP's code works because you are accessing to a value of a variable called `localStorage` with global scope, but you are not accessing to the browser `localStorage` functionality. It's simply if you know fine how the scopes works in javascript.

Comment: Downvoter, show your face. This is the good correct question. LocalStorage is overriding by an array, that's not correct and it crashes

Comment: Marcos, your reply is incorrect. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Basic_concepts, `You can access these values like an object, or with the getItem() and setItem() methods`.

Comment: @Marco `You can access these values like an object, or with the getItem() and setItem() methods` yeah, but if you know that `undefined` keyword is not a valid JSON value, you'll never use the object accessing to localStorage to avoid that error.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, I'm not trolling. I'm simply saying that accessing localStorage as an object is perfectly fine. You said: `you are overriding the localStorage global object with your own values, so you lost the functionality.`. This isn't true. Try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: Sorry if I disturb you. I believe you. The problem here is not only trying to get a value from localstorage with object notation, the problem is by that method values can be stored incorrectly, and when an `undefined` keyword will be passed to `JSON.parse()` or `JSON.stringify()` it crashes with the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`. In this error, `u` is the first letter of `undefined`. You understand me now?

Comment: This isn't what you said in your reply though... Anyway, you can store incorrect values with `setItem()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have only just started using localStorqage myself, but it looks like you should be using window.localStorage.setItem() and window.localStorage.getItem()

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Reusable Approach** like this.

```js
export const localData = {
    set(key, value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    },
    get(key) {
        const stored = localStorage.getItem(key);
        return stored == null ? undefined : JSON.parse(stored);
    },
    remove(key, value) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
};

localData.set("user_name", "serialCoder")
console.log( "After set ", localData.get("user_name") )

localData.remove("user_name")
console.log( "After remove ", localData.get("user_name") )
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use

```
localStorage.setItem('allContracts', JSON.stringify(allContracts));
localStorage.getItem('allContracts');
```

More details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @gnerkus the answer is good, but he doesn't explain why. The problem is the OP is overriding the localstorage because he doesn't use the methods.