# Save complete JSON in session storage

Tags: javascript, fetch, session-storage

I have a website getting data from an external API. I would like to save all the data from the API in session storage (not only one object but the whole result from the fetch request). 
I am able to do that, but then I cannot reuse the data when I reload the page. The data is stored but it cannot be used by the function.

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("data") == null) { 
fetch('XXX')    
.then(function(resp) { return resp.json() }) 
.then(function(data) {
    APIresults(data);
    sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))
})
    .catch(function() {
    });

}
// This first part seems to works - now second part when user already have data in sessionstorage

     else if (sessionStorage.getItem("data") != null) { 
    let data = sessionStorage.getItem("data");
        function workingresults (data) {
            APIresults(data);
        };

    }
    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: That's because the data in the session storage is stored as a string. By doing `JSON.parse(data)` after you read it from the storage, you'll be able to access it as a object.

Answer (score 0):

Like @LuudJacobs said you have to use `JSON.parse()` like this:

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem("data") == null) { 
fetch('XXX')    
.then(function(resp) { return resp.json() }) 
.then(function(data) {
    APIresults(data);
    sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))
})
    .catch(function() {
    });

}
// This first part seems to works - now second part when user already have data in sessionstorage

     else if (sessionStorage.getItem("data") != null) { 
    let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("data"));
        function workingresults (data) {
            APIresults(data);
        };

    }
    }
```

More on the topic:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Similar question:

[JSON.parse() from localStorage issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273539/json-parse-from-localstorage-issue)

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

When loading data into storage, you need to string it as an object so that you can retrieve and use the data. Json.you used stringfy, but you're trying to get it as a string when you're getting the data you're loading. Json.You should use Parse.

```
let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("data")); // just added JSON.Parse method.
```